# Modifying Windows System sounds

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-4.0

I'm trying to change the Windows' system sounds for example startup sound or shutdown sound but all my solutions don't work. 
I can't replace any file of C:\Windows\Media folder, even If I change permissions and change the UAC (User Account Control) to be "never notify".

So any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: *"my solutions don't work"* this is **not** a technical description of a problem. How can we possibly tell you why they dont work, unless you want us to search google for you and find a solution (which is not what we do). Please narrow your question to a specific problem and add any references code and exceptions you are getting

Comment: Don't touch that folder. Those are registry settings. You *could* find them (under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) and edit to point to a path of your choosing.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes you are right about my description "my solutions didn't work" but I already mentioned my tries. First I tried to replace the sound files in  C:/Windows/media but they protected by the system and then I tried to stop the UAC and the same result also I spent all the day searching on google and I found some questions like mine but most of them are non programming solutions (for example, changing by the control panel)

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be related to *any* of the tags. What are you *really* looking for?

Comment: @IInspectable I want to change the windows' system sounds via c# or vb.net

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the registry to enable the related settings occurs in sounds setting.
By default, there is no exit Window option like this:

[image]

Find the registry entry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\SystemExit`  And edit the value of `ExcludeFromCPL` from 1 to 0.

[image]

Then you will see `Exit Windows` option in sounds setting. Try to change the sound you want.

[image]

Same with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsLogon` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels\WindowsLogoff`.

Comment: Under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\[SoundType]\.Current` there's the actual path of the file  that is used to produce that sound. It can be set to anything.

Comment: Thank you Rita this was a very helpful answer and the @Jimi answer was the exactly what I want. Now I'm trying to edit the registry value by c# but it creates another value called (default) instead of edit it